# What would the actor be in a use case where stock is reordered automatically when it hits a certain point

Tags: uml, use-case

Say there is 5 bags of potatoes, when it hits two bags, an order is sent to the supplier automatically. Who/What is the actor?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you have an actor to watch the queue like this:

[image]

Even if the `Potato Watcher` is something implemented inside the SUC, it would be an actor on its own. You may drag it inside the SUC boundary. In a final implementation it might be a system task to poll a queue or a subscriber to the queue. But from the added value viewpoint it's just a simple actor to watch a queue and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since "an order is sent... automatically" the system is the actor. Assuming you are automating using software system.

However in real life it all goes wrong and businesses are far away from sending orders automatically.
Badgerbadger, you need to be carefull about statement "sent an order".
It is easy to overlook actual business process and previous subfunction-level answers are giving a nudge.

More realistic scenario is that the *system is the actor who just initiates* the check of stocks, maybe orchestrates. And then there is a complicated process of getting approval, finding budget, checking if goods are really required to be ordered and so on. In theory all of those can be automated, but usually *in practice there is a work for human actor as well*. Of course you may be lucky and avoid all of this.

Example of pessimistic scenario to consider:

1. It was eight bags, but now hits three. John just bought five bags from us, hooray!
2. System automatically places an order and pays for 10 more bags.
3. In ten minutes someone ordered one more.
4. System automatically places an order again and pays for 10 more bags.

   - We don't have enough money on account so we are facing overdraft.
5. At the same time regular inspection found that one bag is rotten.
6. System: 10 more bags please!

   - Our colleague just told us that we've missed 20% discount from supplier on simultaneous orders of 25+ bags which can be obtained only by calling a company manager.
7. John cancels his order in an hour after placing it.

   - Now we have 36 bags and a hole in our budget.
   - And our marketing manager just told us that the green bags system ordered are actually now selling with a discount, we are getting rid of them in favour of new line of blue bags.

Answer (score -2):

You have to possibilities here:

1. Each time the stock is used the system checks if the condition to order is met and if yes then order it. As ordering will probably involve another actor (e.g. supplier's system), you might need to model it as a separate UC and use extend relationship. In this case you will not have any additional actor initiating the order, only the actor initiating stock usage.
2. The system checks on a regular basis what stocks reached the automated order level and make a single mass order. In this case you'll have to model Scheduler as an actor (in reality it's another system running on the server so it's fine to call it an actor). Some people prefer modelling such actor as "time" but it's discouraged.

Comment: Downvoting this answer because the differentiation that you make is not relevant to answering the question.